# Proving the Shoelace Formula with Elementary Calculus?

Tags: calculus, integration

The shoelace formula [found here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) or [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Shoelace_Theorem) tells you how to calculate the area of any polygon given its coordinates.

The second link I mentioned gives a proof of it, but it is a bit beyond my level of comprehension. Could anyone try to simplify the proof (or provide their own) to a level up to and including single variable calculus?

Comment: Take a look at this [article](http://poncelet.math.nthu.edu.tw/disk5/js/cardioid/12.pdf), which provides a very accessible proof. You don't need much background other than a familiarity with basic vector geometry and the basic notion of a determinant (just for $2\times 2$ matrices).

Comment: @EuYu One part I didn't understand was why you need to go in a counter-clockwise order. Isn't the area of the large polygon the sum of the areas of the triangles? Why would it matter which points you choose to take the area?

Comment: Each triangle's area breaks up into three terms, one for each edge. The terms are positive or negative depending on the orientations of the triangles. Since the diagonals of the triangulation are not a part of the original polygon you need them to cancel. The only way to do that is for all the triangles to be oriented the same way. By convention we choose counterclockwise as positive, so all the triangles are oriented that way.

Comment: Another way to think about it is in terms of signed areas. The area is positive if oriented counterclockwise and negative if oriented clockwise. The triangles need to be oriented the same way otherwise the areas have different sign and cancel each other.

Comment: Updated Link: http://steiner.math.nthu.edu.tw/disk5/js/cardioid/12.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple induction proof can be based on this fact [[*]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83580/every-polygon-has-an-interior-diagonal):

> Every simple polygon has a *diagonal*, that is, a segment joining two non-consecutive vertices that lies totally inside the polygon.

Take the polygon and split it along a diagonal. The area of the polygon is the sum of the areas of the two parts. By induction, these areas are given by the formula. When you combine them, the terms corresponding to the diagonal cancel.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a really good response I found on YahooAnswers a while ago:

> The proof in the link is sheer madness.
>
> For this clockwise order to make sense, you need a point $O$ inside the
>   polygon so that the angles  form $(OA_i, OA_{i+1})$ and $(OA_n,OA_1)$ be all positive.
>
> Then the formula is just adding up the areas of the triangles
>   $OA_iA_{i+1}$ and $OA_nA_1$.
>
> So all you need is area of $ OA_1A_2 = \dfrac {b_2a_1-b_1a_2}{2} $, which is
>   elementary.

So here's my summary of the above answer:

1. I don't quite agree that the AoPS proof is sheer madness $-$ it is pretty rigorous and I like it, in the long run.
2. Pick a point $O$ inside the polygon so that we have positive angles.
3. You want the sum of the areas $\left[\triangle OA_iA_{i+1}\right]+\left[\triangle OA_nA_1\right]$ over all points $A_i$.
4. Using the area of a triangle, we have $ \left[\triangle OA_1 A_2\right] = \dfrac {b_2a_1 - b_1 a_2}{2} $. Summing over all indices, you get the desired result.

$ \blacksquare $

Comment: This will only work for rather simple polygons. It's not always true that you can pick a point such that all the angles are positive (take a C shaped polygon for example).

Comment: @user2612743 Area of a triangle.

Comment: @EuYu Part of the conditions of the Shoelace Theorem is convexity.

Comment: @AhaanRungta No it's not. The shoelace formula applies for any simple polygon. The example picture in the wikipedia article itself is non-convex.

Comment: ++ for a bunch of helpful data. :-)